# Scheduler Implementation for multiple schedules in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cron, scheduler

I am working on implementing a scheduler with the below requirements.
On scheduling a task, I add an entry in my database jobs table with a CRON expression and a tag to identify what method needs to be run in the code.

I am using **BackgroundService** provided by the .NET Core to periodically fetch the data from my jobs table. I want to be able to run the required code using the cron expression and the tag which I have mentioned.

A sample of my expected behavior would be as below.

```
public class SchedulerBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseService _databaseService;

        public SchedulerBackgroundService(IDatabaseService databaseService)
        {
            this._databaseService = databaseService;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var jobsFromDb = await _databaseService.GetActiveJobs();

                try
                {
                    foreach (var job in jobsFromDb)
                    {
                        var schedule = NCrontab.CrontabSchedule.Parse(job.CronExpression);
                        var nextOccurance = schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);

                        if (DateTime.Now > nextOccurance)
                        {
                            if (job.Tag == "First")
                            {
                                ProcessFirst();
                            }
                            else if (job.Tag == "Second")
                            {
                                ProcessSecond();
                            }
                        }
                        await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken); //5 seconds delay
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // log
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This would not work as the condition **DateTime.Now > nextOccurance** would always be false as the nextOccurance is calculated using the DateTime.Now

Is there any other way to make this work without storing the nextOccurence as one of the column to the database.

I have gone through some articles which suggest using some libraries like Quartz, but most of them provide an example just schedule a single job where the CRON expression is constant throughout.

I want a single background service to handle all the kinds of processing. So the CRON expression cannot be constant.
Please help with any useful suggestions on implementing this functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to make this work without storing the nextOccurence as one of the column to the database.

Store the *last* occurence in the database, and pass that to `GetNextOccurrence`.